# Track Solana wallet change in Web

Tags: websocket, solana, solana-web3js

I'm building a Web3 app while using Solana. 
I'm using [`@solana/wallet-adapter`](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter) for wallet connection

**Code:**

```
const Wallet = ({ children }) => {
// The network can be set to 'devnet', 'testnet', or 'mainnet-beta'.
const network = WalletAdapterNetwork.Devnet;

// You can also provide a custom RPC endpoint.
const endpoint = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl(network), [network]);

// @solana/wallet-adapter-wallets includes all the adapters but supports tree shaking and lazy loading --
// Only the wallets you configure here will be compiled into your application and only the dependencies
// of wallets that your users connect to will be loaded.
const wallets = useMemo(
() => [
   new PhantomWalletAdapter(),
   new SlopeWalletAdapter(),
   new SolflareWalletAdapter(),
   new TorusWalletAdapter(),
   new LedgerWalletAdapter(),
   new SolletWalletAdapter({ network }),
   new SolletExtensionWalletAdapter({ network }),
],[network]);

return (
  <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
    <WalletProvider wallets={wallets} autoConnect>
      <WalletModalProvider>
        <WalletMultiButton />
        <WalletDisconnectButton />
        {children}
      </WalletModalProvider>
    </WalletProvider>
  </ConnectionProvider>
);
};
```

It's a basic components. Same as a presented in `@solana/wallet-adapter` [docs](https://solana-labs.github.io/wallet-adapter/#solanawallet-adapter)

**The problem:**
After connecting some wallet manager(let's say Phantom, for instance), I'm getting all the information I need. **But** after changing wallet -- I don't see any updates in my app.

**The question is** 
How can I handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a couple of days of research, I came to the conclusion that this is an **API bug**.

I found a way that allows you to find out if the account has changed or not. It can be used if it is critical for you:

```
const isAccountChanged = window.solana.publicKey.toBase58() !== `${your_current_public_key}`;

if (isAccountChanged) {
  // do some updates
}
```

For now, you can create `setInterval`(for instance) to detect these changes. So, if `isAccountChanged = true` -> you need to update the users state. If it's still `false` -> you can wait.

**fyi:**

- https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/issues/49
- https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/pull/109

Comment: Cool, but how can I tell wallet adapter that a PublicKey of connected wallet changed? So when I call e.g. `currentWallet.sendTransaction()`, it will send it to updated wallet and not old wallet instead?